# Can't get Fiddler to capture HttpClient web api calls from MVC with localhost different port

Tags: c#, asp.net, fiddler

Yet another fiddler can't get it to capture post.

Similar to this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16994111/cant-get-fiddler-to-capture-local-traffic-to-iis) I have spent two hours now reading and trying different solution yet none of them allow me to see my fiddler web api traffic.

As a side note my code is working I am just focused on getting fiddler to show me the api calls.

I will describe my setup then what I have tried.

My Web API is a separate MVC 6, EF 7 project running on port 63381

> http://localhost:63381/

My ASP.NET MVC 5 web client project is running on port: 59722

> http://localhost:59722/

A typical action controller in the mvc client:

```
//Controller CTOR
public ClientController()
{
  client = new HttpClient();
  client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:63381/api/MyApi");
  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
}

//Action within ClientController
public async Task<JsonResult> AddNewSubCategory()
{
   HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(url2, content);
   if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
   {
     return Json("[{Update Success}]", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }
     return Json("[{Error Updating}]", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }
}
```

1. Added the  block to 32 & 62 machine.config. Restarted visual studio did *NOT* restart machine or any other service. This did not work.
2. Added the  block to the client web.config and this didn't work.
3. Changed localhost to machinename:port
   Specifically I changed http://localhost:63381/api/MyApi to http://gpgvm-pc:63381/api/MyApi
4. Modified Global.asax with:

   ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(delegate { return true; });
5. Fiddler custom rules
6. Reverse proxy
7. Set fiddler listening on a different port.

At this point I surrender. It seems to me #1 should work to capture everything but I am obviously still doing something wrong because I can get fiddler to capture one or the other but NOT the client calling off to the client???

---

Update:

My machine locked and after reboot I started seeing the api calls so this issue was something with my machine. So sorry to bother.

Comment: Any filters set up in Fiddler?

Comment: Nope. Sorry didn't mention that I checked in OP.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is most likely that you are using localhost which are handled in a special way.

Try using machine name or your ip instead (do not use 127.0.0.1).

The documentation have information about this as well:

http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Observe-Traffic/Troubleshooting/NoTrafficToLocalhost

Comment: I did try the machine name...see point 3 in OP. Now it is possible I didn't do it correctly. I'll update OP with what I tried.

Comment: HttpClient is giving me invalid hostname when I try to call out from mvc client to api.

Comment: Try changing to your ip instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to hit specific action in api then use that code in webapi config

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)

        {
            //config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            //    name: "DefaultApi",
            //    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            //    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

           config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("API Default", "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

        }
```

This code where u call your api.

```
 public ActionResult ClientController(model content)

        {
            try
            {
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient("http://localhost:63381/");
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/MyApi/url2", content).Result;
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    return Json(new { code = 0, message = "Success" });
                }
                else
                {
                    return Json(new { code = -1, message = "Failed" });
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                int code = -2;
                return Json(new { code = code, message = "Failed" });
            }
        }
}
```